# PHP script returns an unexpected value to the AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My javascript:

```
nombre = window.prompt('Escribe el nombre del autor/artista/letrista:','');
    if(nombre != ''){
      $.ajax({
          url: "admin/nuevo_autor.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {autor: nombre},
          success: function (res) {
              alert(res);
              if(res=='verdadero'){
                  var opt = document.createElement('option');
                  opt.text = nombre;
                  opt.selected = true;
                  sel.add(opt);
              }
              return true;
          }
      });
    }
```

Calls 'nuevo_autor.php':

```
<?php
$nuevo = $_POST["autor"];
require("../includes/database.php");

$select = <<<EOT
SELECT * FROM autor
WHERE 1
EOT;
$resultado = $mysqli->query($select);
$res = "verdadero";
for($i=0;$i<$resultado->num_rows; $i++){
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if(stristr($fila["autor"], $nuevo)) {
        $res = "falso";
        break;
    }
}
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

The Javascript alert shows: **FIN** (in spanish: **END**). Neither '**verdadero**' nor '**falso**'.
I also tested using the `$.get` jQuery function with the same bad result.
Where is the error?

Comment: just do `echo $res;` then in ajax have `dataType:'text',`

Comment: You're using heredoc output before the JSON is outputted ?

Answer (score 0):

`stristr($fila["autor"], $nuevo)` will return "0" if $nuevo and $fila['author'] are equal, which in your code will be the equivalent of `false`.

Instead you need to explicitly check for the `false` value, as in:

```
if(stristr($fila["autor"], $nuevo) !== false) {
    $res = "falso";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but the problem is that no value ('verdadero' nor 'falso') is returned. Only 'FIN'.